# Laravel - Gates Multiple Or in middleware

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel gates in my web.php, where i add middleware for can as follows

```
Route::post('/sellproducts', 'ProductController@Sell')->middleware('auth')->middleware('can:admin');
```

i want to add another rule for example can:admin or can:moderator so either of them is true, gate will allow

any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use a logical or operator when enabling middleware for a route.

You could make a third Gate, that returns true when the user is either admin or moderator.

Another option is that you would create a `ProductPolicy`. In this policy you could create a `sellProduct()` method that checks if the user has the right roles:

```
public function sellProduct(User $user, Product $product) 
{
    // Return true when user is moderator or admin
}
```

You would have to call this method in your `ProductController@Sell` with:

```
$this->authorize('sellProduct', $product);
```

Take attention that gates and policies are meant to determine if a user is authorized to perform an action. This can be done by checking if the user has a certain role, or if the user is the owner of, in your case, a product. When you define a Gate as `'admin'` things could get mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::post('/sellproducts', 'ProductController@Sell')->middleware('auth, can:admin');
```